# how to input new string if there have value except zero

Tags: java, mysql

i need help. can somebody tell me about concept and example code i need use? the case is, I want input game history using **java** into **mysql** (phpmyadmin).

I'm already create like this if `S0: 1.0;` and all value zero

```
try
{
   connection = dbManager.getConnection();    
   String bs = "S0:"+s[0]+"; S1:"+s[1]+"; S2:"+s[2]+"; S3:"+s[3]+"; S4:"+s[4]+"; S5:"+s[5]+"; S6:"+s[6]+"; S7:"+s[7]+"; S8:"+s[8]+"; S9:"+s[9]+"; S10:"+s[10]+"; S11:"+s[11]+"; S12:"+s[12]+"; S13:"+s[13]+"; S14:"+s[14]+"; S15:"+s[15]+"; S16:"+s[16]+"; S17:"+s[17]+"; S18:"+s[18]+"; S19:"+s[19]+"; S20:"+s[20]+"; S21:"+s[21]+"; S22:"+s[22]+"; S23:"+s[23]+"; S24:"+s[24]+"; S25:"+s[25]+"; S26:"+s[26]+"; S27:"+s[27]+"; S28:"+s[28]+"; S29:"+s[29]+"; S30:"+s[30]+"; S31:"+s[31]+"; S32:"+s[32]+"; S33:"+s[33]+"; S34:"+s[34]+"; S35:"+s[35]+"; S36:"+s[36]+"";
}
catch (SQLException e)
{
   trace("player 1 update error");
}
```

and it's working and result like this

```
S0:1.0; S1:0.0; S2:0.0; S3:0.0; S4:0.0; S5:0.0; S6:0.0; S7:0.0; S8:0.0; S9:0.0; S10:0.0; S11:0.0; S12:0.0; S13:0.0; S14:0.0; S15:0.0; S16:0.0; S17:0.0; S18:0.0; S19:0.0; S20:0.0; S21:0.0; S22:0.0; S23:0.0; S24:0.0; S25:0.0; S26:0.0; S27:0.0; S28:0.0; S29:0.0; S30:0.0; S31:0.0; S32:0.0; S33:0.0; S34:0.0; S35:0.0; S36:0.0
```

but it's not efficient, the question is how i can input if there have any value except zero, example like `S0:1 ; S1:0 ; S2:1` and insert into mysql just like this `S0:1 ; S2:1` so if there no have value / zero, not being inserted. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
String bs = "";
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if(!s[i].equals(0.0)) {
        if(count > 0) {
            bs += " ; " ;
        }
        bs += "S" + count + ":" + s[i].split(".")[0];
        count++;
    }

}
```

Comment: i think it's more simple for what i need it, and i just try your code before you edit it, and working. thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
private static String format (int x) {

    if (x == 0) {
        return null;
    }

    return String.format ("S%d = %d; ", x ,x);
}

 // testing from main

   {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
        for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++) {   // dummy input stream
            String rv = format (x);
            if (rv != null) {
                buf.append(rv);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(buf.toString());
    }
```