# How to insert string data except string have value zero to database

Tags: java, mysql

I want to insert all string to database except string have zero value, example S:1,B:0,D:1 .So in mysql will insert (S:1 , D:1 ) there's no B:0, because B have zero value. 
Anyone can give me example code how to do that,
i tried with this :

```
String betsmall= "S:"+0;
String betbig= "B:"+1;
String bet1= "B1:"+0;
String bet2= "B2:"+1;

connection = dbManager.getConnection();
 PreparedStatement stmts = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT MYSQL");
stmts.setString(4, betsmall + ","+ betbig + "," + bet1 + "," +bet2);
```

with that code, the result in database is S:0,B:1,B1:0,B2:1.

but i want the result will be like this B:1,B2:1.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325768/how-to-input-new-string-if-there-have-value-except-zero/39325892#39325892

Comment: @ScaryWombat, not really, as far as I can see, though the relationship is easy to see.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String validText = "B1";
    String invalidText = "B0";

    if(containsZero(validText)) {
        //Persist in database here
    }

    if(containsZero(invalidText)) {
        //Persist in database here
    }
}

private static boolean containsZero(String text) {
    return text.contains("0");
}
```

This is the simplest way.

Comment: It can probably be refined. My guess is that `B:10` and `S:101` don’t count as having zero value and should be persisted. A quick and dirty solution would be `text.endsWith(":0")`. A more bulletproof solution would parse the text following the colon as an integer and compare it to 0.